# Website doesn't display full-screen background properly once user changes orientation

Tags: android, jquery, html, css

Below is my code for displaying a full-screen background image and also has some basic function for detecting whether the device's width is larger than the height:

```
.
.
.
<script src="srobbin-jquery-backstretch-241a345/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
.
.
.
<body>
    <script>
    if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth)
    {
        $.backstretch("Assets/Cover.jpg");
    }
    else
    {
        $.backstretch("Assets/Cover-Landscape.jpg");
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It works ok, except that it can't seem to refresh and display the image correctly when the user changes the device's orientation.
If the device is already in landscape orientation before I enter the site in the browser, then it's fine.

See image:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your conditional `if` is actually only called when you load the page. You have to use an *event handler* to detect the window re-sizing like:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth){
    $.backstretch("Assets/Cover.jpg");
  } else {
    $.backstretch("Assets/Cover-Landscape.jpg");
  }
});
```

**EDIT:**
So now you also have to bind this to also be called at loading.

```
$(window).on("load resize",function(e){
  if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth){
    $.backstretch("Assets/Cover.jpg");
  } else {
    $.backstretch("Assets/Cover-Landscape.jpg");
  }
});
```

This would actually be better.

Comment: Marvelous, Redbreast! Works perfectly! :-) Accepted the answer.